# performance with large items select in element ui ?

Tags: element-ui

I have 3000 items I used **Element UI** select but it very slow with large Select Lists, any help

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of options to display without any filtering.  Have you looked at the "remote search" feature of `select`?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at remote search feature.Where user can enter keywords and search data from server accordingly

see the [docs](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select#remote-search)